# Failure starting carthagenet.sh with --rpc-port option

Tags: rpc, docker, ubuntu, testnet

I am trying to start `carthagenet.sh` in RPC mode on Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ ./carthagenet.sh start --rpc-port 8732
```

It appears to start fine:

```
v7.0: Pulling from tezos/tezos
Digest: sha256:da126e8d6bf137a9b326c3992c0e464622b94e2ee42b7d311df158212b8ae153
Status: Image is up to date for tezos/tezos:v7.0
docker.io/tezos/tezos:v7.0
Creating network "carthagenet_default" with the default driver
Creating carthagenet_node_1     ... done
Creating carthagenet_upgrader_1                   ... done
Creating carthagenet_baker-006-PsCARTHA-test_1    ... done
Creating carthagenet_endorser-alpha-test_1        ... done
Creating carthagenet_endorser-006-PsCARTHA_1      ... done
Creating carthagenet_baker-006-PsCARTHA_1         ... done
Creating carthagenet_accuser-alpha_1              ... done
Creating carthagenet_accuser-006-PsCARTHA-test_1  ... done
Creating carthagenet_accuser-alpha-test_1         ... done
Creating carthagenet_endorser-006-PsCARTHA-test_1 ... done
Creating carthagenet_baker-alpha-test_1           ... done
Creating carthagenet_endorser-alpha_1             ... done
Creating carthagenet_baker-alpha_1                ... done
Creating carthagenet_accuser-006-PsCARTHA_1       ... done
```

However, as soon as I run any command I get an error:

```
$ ./carthagenet.sh client list known addresses
Error response from daemon: Container 9920d6b346868d3d5491c0cd88eee100189c470d2107fa49cde6086568ec1383 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

I used the following command to debug issues with the docker container:

```
docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps 9920d6b346868d3d5491c0cd88eee100189c470d21
```

It appears the docker container keeps trying to restart with this error message:

```
2020-05-14T07:02:29.592446544Z Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
2020-05-14T07:02:29.593149945Z Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
2020-05-14T07:02:29.593724545Z Updating the node configuration...
2020-05-14T07:02:29.666034593Z tezos-node: unknown option `--rpc-port'.
2020-05-14T07:02:29.666059993Z Usage: tezos-node config [OPTION]... [OPERATION]
2020-05-14T07:02:29.666064593Z Try `tezos-node config --help' or `tezos-node --help' for more information.
```

All documentation I find seems to suggest --rpc-port is the correct option. Where could I be having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `carthagenet.sh` has a bug. Documentation in the file says we should run

```
./carthagenet.sh start --rpc-port 8732
```

Doing this will update the `.tezos-carthagenet/docker-compose.yml` to have the following command and ports:

```
command: tezos-node --network carthagenet --rpc-port 8732
ports:
  - "19732:19732"
```

However, as I said in my question, the docker container will not start because of the unexpected `--rpc-port` argument being passed in. So, I took a look at the `update_compose_file()` method in the bash script that updates the `docker-compose.yml` file before the container starts:

```
update_compose_file() {
    ...

    if [ "$#" -ge 2 ] && [ "$1" = "--rpc-port" ] ; then
        export_rpc="
      - \"$2:8732\""
        shift 2
    fi

    cat > "$docker_compose_yml" <<EOF
    ...
}
```

If `if` statement never gets executed because `$1` contains the string `--network`. Remember the argument array will look like:

```
$1: --network
$2: carthagenet
$3: --rpc-port
$4: 8732
```

We need to change the if statement to read `"$3" = "--rpc-port"`. Similarly, with that fixed, we need to update the conditional code to contain `$4:8732`, not `$2`, as well as update `shift 2` to `shift 4` to erase both sets of arguments for the rest of the bash script to run properly.

Rerunning the `./carthagenet.sh start --rpc-port 8732` command will then update the `docker-compose.yml` file correctly to

```
command: tezos-node --net-addr :19732
ports:
  - "19732:19732"
  - "8732:8732"
```

allowing RPC calls to work from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The node fails to start because --rpc-port is being added to the Docker Compose start command arguments for the tezos-node executable. The correct exec switch is --rpc-addr. The current documentation is incorrect or inconsistent. An alternative tool that helps you manages mainnet, zeronet, and carthagenet containers is teztool. https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/teztool

Docker Compose

```
/Users/username/.tezos-carthagenet/docker-compose.yml
```

**Carthagenet Command**

```
./carthagenet.sh start --rpc-addr 8732
```

Comment: I think he was referring to this: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/latest-release/scripts/tezos-docker-manager.sh#L34-38 where it modifies the docker-compose file.